# How do I make OpenapiGenerator to generate models when defined inline?

Tags: swagger, openapi-generator

I tried running `java -jar openapi-generator-cli.jar generate -i 'swagger.json' -g scala-akka -o scala_client` but it didn't produce any modules (doesn't work with Java nor Clojure).

Running `java -jar openapi-generator-cli.jar  generate -c config.yaml -i 'swagger.json' -g scala-akka  -o scala_client --generate-alias-as-model` (also without config and/or without `--generate-alias-as-model`), doesn't produce any model libs either.

Removing `"additionalProperties": false,` from the inline schema def makes it generate model classes. What also works is to define the schema using `definitions` + `"$ref" : "..."` - but neither of those are feasible with the library I'm using for my server.

I don't quite understand why it won't generate the models. Can't seem to find an answer anywhere, am I missing something simple?

[My swagger.json](https://gist.github.com/davidginzbourg/e52f696d835f1caf885900fbad888204)

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the only issue is that your are using a 2.0 version of the OpenAPI-Specification. One can easily migrate to version 3.* (try [THIS](https://mermade.org.uk/openapi-converter) for example), then the models will be generated (for me it worked with scala-akka and java-spring)

[transformed_to_3.0.0.json](https://github.com/superplan/stackoverflow/blob/main/openapi_3.0.0.json)

Comment: I used the CLI version of the converter, and it magically made this whole thing work. I also noticed that my original definition (the one that inspired the example I gave) was missing an info.version attribute. But I still had to use the converter to get all of the inline models I defined. Thank you!